# rails add id's to table with button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using rails 4.
And I need to add user.id and place.id to subsriptions table.
I got:

```
  class AddPlaceidToUserid < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      create_table :subscriptions do |t|
        t.integer :placeid
        t.integer :userid
      end
    end
  end
```

in places_cntroller.rb i got

```
def addid
  @sub = Subscription.new(sub_params)
  @sub.userid = current_user.id
  @sub.placeid = place.id
end

private

def sub_params
  params.require(:subscription).permit(:placeid, :userid)
end
```

In index.html.erb of places i got:

```
<%= button_to "subscribe", :controller => :places, 
                           :action => 'addid',
                           :method => :post %>
```

and in routes i got:

```
resources :places do
  post :addid, :on => :collection
end
```

and when i click on button i got params not found: subscription error. What shuold i change? or where i can find similar tutorial?

Comment: a) You should first learn to follow Rails conventions - method names, as well as foreign key columns, should be named with underscore, like `user_id`, `place_id`, `add_id`.
b) If you learn how to name your columns properly, you can easily use Rails associations:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class AddPlaceidToUserid < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :subscriptions do |t|
      t.integer :place_id
      t.integer :user_id
    end
  end
end
```

no need for a collection.

```
resources :places do
  post :addid
end
```

your controller

```
def addid
  @sub = Subscription.new(sub_params)
  if @sub.save 
     ...
  else 
     ...
  end 
end
```